# calculate the number of different lottery columns

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many different lottery columns exist(of length $13$,with $1,2 \text{ or } X \text{ at each position}$) ?

I have to use this theorem:

> Let $k$ a natural number and $E$ the set of all different $(x_1,x_2, \dots , x_k)$,where $x_1 \in E_1, x_2 \in E_2, \dots, x_k \in E_k$ and $E_j$ are finite.Then $|E|=|E_1| \cdot |E_2| \cdots |E_k|$.

Could you help me?
Is it maybe $13^3$,or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it $3^{13}$?

If $E_1=E_2=\ldots=E_k=\{1,X,2\}$ and $k=13$, then $|E_i|=3$ for all $i=1,\ldots,13$ and
$$|E|=|E_1|\cdot\ldots\cdot|E_{13}|=3^{13}.$$